# Render the content of an object from Firebase with map() using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use onSnapshot to render in real time the result in my HTML, like so:

```
const collectionRef = collection(db, 'notes');

onSnapshot(collectionRef, (snapshot) => {    
    let notes = []
    let html = '';

    const noteList = document.querySelector('.notes');

    snapshot.docs.map(function(doc) {
      notes.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
      const li = `
        <li>
          <div class="note-title"> ${notes.title} </div>
          <div class="note-content"> ${notes.content} </div>
        </li>
      `;
      html += li
    })

    const noteList = document.querySelector('.notes');
    noteList.innerHTML = html;
})
```

But all I'm getting is multiple "undefined" printed on the HTML.. I tried JSON.parse or stringify to no avail. What do I have to do to print this new populated "notes" array in the page?

PS: I can print something (e.g. the 1st title) if I use ${notes[0].title} but I'm stuck to print all values from the firebase.. I bet it's simple.

Comment: try with `${doc.title}` so on inside and the map

Answer (score 1):

Well, I put the notes object in a simple for loop and BOOM, it solved it (I feel dumb now, but I'm letting this here to help others) :)))

```
const collectionRef = collection(db, 'notes');

onSnapshot(collectionRef, (snapshot) => {       
    let notes = []
    let html = '';

    snapshot.docs.map(function(doc) {

      notes.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });

    });

    for(var i=0; i<notes.length; i++) {
      const li = `
        <li>
          <div class="note-title"> ${notes[i].title} </div>
          <div class="note-content"> ${notes[i].content} </div>
        </li>
      `;
      
      html += li;
    }

    console.log(notes, "NOTES");

    const noteList = document.querySelector('.notes');
    noteList.innerHTML = html;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the `title` and `content` properties off of the `notes` *array*. Instead, you can use [`DocumentSnapshot#get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot#documentsnapshotget):

```js
 const li = `
  <li>
    <div class="note-title"> ${doc.get("title")} </div>
    <div class="note-content"> ${doc.get("content")} </div>
  </li>
`;
```

(You could also use `doc.data().title` and `doc.data().content`)

Comment: Perfect answer! Mine also works but yours is the right one as it doesn't need another for loop .. Thank you so much!